# How to do mathematical manipulation on individual's value with OWL?

Tags: rdf, owl, rdfs

How to do mathematical manipulation on value then inference today and yesterday by xsd:datetimie with OWL?

classes

```
day
  today
  yestoday
```

individuals

```
A data property hasDatetime = 20180613 xsd:int or xsd:datetime
```

i label A is today

to infer

```
B is yesterday basedOn A hasDatetime - 1
```

1. can i do this with OWL ?
2. can i do mathematical manipulation on value of xsd:type?

Comment: What? How should a reasoner "infer" this? An OWL reasoner is not a math engine. And what is `xsd:type`?

Comment: xsd:interger etc..., great i think this somehow explain my other post, "the member -guest"

Comment: OWL doesn't "modify" anything. It's about monotonic reasoning.